# sammy.js get handler hiding errors

Tags: javascript, error-handling, sammy.js

While using **sammy.js** library of versions  **0.7.4** (also **0.7.1**) it was found that if some error happens during execution of `get` handler function, nothing is printed to console.

For example in the following code snippet nothing will be printed to console though no function with name `notExistingFunction` exists:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <script src="/path/to/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/path/to/sammy-0.7.4.min.js"></script>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var sammy = Sammy(function() {
                    this.get('#someAnchor', function() {
                        // this function doesn't exist
                        notExistingFunction();
                    });
                });
                sammy.run();

                // this should lead to execution of above handler
                window.location.hash = '#someAnchor'; 
            });
        </script>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

This really complicates troubleshooting of pages, did someone experienced this as well? Is this expected behavior or a bug? Are there any workarounds for this?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be easier than I thought - after inspecting sources of **sammy.js** it was found that somewhy `raise_errors` flag is set to `false` by default which manages error reporting.

So, modifying part above code to:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <script>
            ...
            sammy.raise_errors = true;
            sammy.run();
            ...
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

starts showing nice errors.